# Nifi artifact visibility/ dependency management

Tags: maven, apache-nifi

I have a two issues with dependency management.

Let's take this example:

- I have custom cache controller service - CustomCacheService

  - groupId - com.example.service
  - artifactId - customcacheservice
- custom processor that queries custom cache - QueryCustomCache

  - groupId - com.example.processor
  - artifactId - querycustomcache
- custom processor that loads custom cache - LoadCustomCache

  - groupId - com.example.processor
  - artifactId - loadcustomcache

***Important note is that I want to use same instance of the CustomCacheService for both processors.***

**First issue is duplication of standard artifacts in GUI list of processors:**
Since both processors have to import a dependency to the CustomCacheService, they both need this dependency in the -nar pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
    <type>nar</type>
</dependency>
```

Without this dependency build will fail with error: Failed to create Extension Documentation
Once I add this dependency, duplicates of standard nifi artifacts will be created for both processors.
Bundle ids for duplicate artifact being processor groupId - artifact (com.example.processor - querycustomcache/ loadcustomcache) and version being my project version (for example: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
Nifi has this dependency imported all over their code and obviously not causing duplicated artifacts.

**Second and more important issue is that I am not able to share CustomCacheService between processors.**
Once I import the service dependency to both processors and load it in nifi, in service list I will have three bundle options for this service:

- CustomCacheService: com.example.processor.querycustomcache    - 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
- CustomCacheService: com.example.processor.loadcustomcache     - 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
- CustomCacheService: com.example.service.customcacheservice    - 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Each processor expects a service instance from it's own bundle.
QueryCustomCache processor expects a service instance from com.example.processor.querycustomcache and does not see any other instances.
Same for LoadCustomCache processor. This makes it unable for me to use same CustomCacheService instance for both processors.
I expect to be able to create CustomCacheService instance with bundle id com.example.service.customcacheservice and use it in both processors.

Both issues are tightly related. My dependencies are organized the same as in nifi source code.

Answer (score 1):

good explanation of your case:

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.0.1/bk_developer-guide/content/nars.html

note the `Nar-Dependency-Id` element in manifest.mf

in short: in your processors you have to import interface of your service and not the implementation

Comment: Thanks for the resource.
I was missing this part:
In order to share this same definition, both the Processor's NAR and the Controller Service Implementation's NAR must have as a Parent the Controller Service definition's NAR.

Processor build would fail with this error: Failed to create Extension Documentation

and I would just add the following dependency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>
 That was causing these issues.